# Showing Snackbar using GetX Library

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, snackbar

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main(List args) {
runApp(GetMaterialApp(
title: 'My App',
home: MyApp(),
));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(),
body: Center(
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [
ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () {
Get.snackbar(
'Hello',
'Hello World!',
snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
);
},
child: Text('GetX Buttom')),
],
),
),
);
}
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

have you imported the `get` package? if not, you can add it in `pubspec.yaml` file, inside `dev_dependencies`.

example:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  get: ^4.6.1
```

then save your pubspec.yaml file and type `flutter pub get` in your terminal

the result will be like this:
[image: image result]

you can read more about getX in [this](https://pub.dev/packages/get) documentation